# Local extrema...found max and min, but question wants "value"?

Tags: calculus

The function $f(x)=6x+9x^-1$ has one local minimum and one local maximum. Here's the question:

$This function has a local maximum at x=______ with value _______   
 and a local minimum at x=_____ with value ______$

I've found the maximum to be $-sqrt(3/2)$ and the minimum to be $sqrt(3/2)$, but I don't know what the question wants for the "value". I put in the value I got by solving $f''(x)$ for the min and max, and it was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should calculate $f\left(-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$ and $f\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$ (value of function at point $x$).

Comment: Ohhhh I see, thank you.